# Запятая и двоеточие.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Павел, меня всегда интересовало, сколько тебе лет?

Павел, меня всегда интересовало: сколько тебе лет?

Здесь запятая или двоеточие ставятся по смысловому оттенку предложения?

Например:

Павел, меня всегда интересовало (можно заменить на **"интересно"**), сколько тебе лет?

Павел,меня всегда интересовало(можно дополнить **"меня всегда интересовало вот что"**):сколько тебе лет?

Возможно ли тире?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Павел, меня всегда интересовало, сколько тебе лет. Это СПП, наименьшее выделение изъяснительной части.

(2) Павел, меня (во что) всегда интересовало: сколько тебе лет? Это БСП, прямой вопрос. Понижение тона перед предупредительной паузой.

(3) Павел, мне (во что) интересно - сколько тебе лет? Тире обозначает подчинительную связь предложений, но без паузы, в более динамичной манере разговорной речи.

Answer (score 1):

София права, здесь возможны все три знака препинания. Это своего рода разговорные предложения, пунктуационная сторона которых остается неразработанной.